# onKeyDown is not working in my code

Tags: java, android

I want to stop music when I press back/home button in my android. I have little code for it but its not working. Could anyone please tell me where I am doing mistake.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you are creating a new instance of `MediaPlayer` and pausing it every time your method is called. You need to get the reference of the currently playing `MediaPlayer` to pause it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    onCreate(...)
    {
       ....
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

            if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                    {
                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                    }
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
    public void SomeOtherFunction()
    {
     mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    //play for example
}
```

this example good work for me. Hope it's help you

it's code for stop/start when pressed on back button

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
 int flag =0;
        onCreate(...)
        {
           ....
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
               if(flag==1)
               {  
                if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                        {
                            mediaPlayer.stop();
                                    flag=0;
                        }
                return true;
               }
               else if(flag==0)
               {

                            mediaPlayer.start();//or play.. forgot
                                    flag=1;

                return true;
               }
            }
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
        public void SomeOtherFunction()
        {
         mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        //play for example and set flag to 1  // flag=1;
    }
```

must work.. but im not tested it.

Comment: thanks for your reply its working fine to stop media player but its not going back from that list. can you help me how to go back when I click back button.

Comment: ya back button is working.But I want to implement same code for home button
@Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
 {
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) 
     {
      
      if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            {
                mediaPlayer.stop();               
                return false;                
            }
     }
     else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
  {
   if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
   {
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    return false;
   }
  }
     else
     {
      return false;
     }

     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }